# Which audio devices does iOS individually save volume output levels for?

Tags: ios, audio

When using an iOS device, I've noticed that when connecting various audio devices, their volume levels are stored separately - as an example, when connecting a pair of EarPods via the Lightning port, the output level produced by my iOS device is different when I then connect a pair of headphones via the Lightning to 3.5mm Adaptor. Is there a definitive list of which audio sources iOS individually saves volume settings for?